# React tree parent node update

Tags: reactjs

I have created a custom tree panel in the react. Every time I update the treeNode which I selected (the state). Now I would like to change the color for root when I select on the child.
I think to do it with refs, adding it for all TreeNodes and then get it using DOM manipulation in React(as I understand it is `ReactDom.finddomnode`)
I have 2 component Tree and TreeNode
The part of code from Tree

```
Tree.js
    <TreeNode ref={(el) => this.treeRef = el}
```

The event click is handle in TreeNode component.
Now I wanna catch this event and update my root. I get an error when using the ReactDom.findDomNode. Any Idea

Comment: you might not need `refs` for this. Can you share a  fiddle ??

Answer (score 0):

You should be using state for showing color of root. Using ref and then manipulating DOM node for such a simple task defeats purpose of React. Refs are used in special situations, this can be done using state/props of react.

I don't know your implementation of Tree, but as an example you can do something like below:

```
render() {
    return <div style={{backgroundColor:this.state.bgColor}}> 
    </div> 
}

changeBGColor(color) {
   this.setState({bgColor:color})

}
```

Now you can pass `changeBGColor` method to child which can then call it to make appropriate color changes. As I have limited information about your implementation I cannot provide you exact solution but I hope this helps.

Comment: I have the next implementation:
Have 2 component Tree and TreeNode
Tree render TreeNode and when I have  children I render Tree.
I have also the current node state for every click

Comment: That's fine, did my answer above make any sense or you need more details...

Comment: That's fine, but there is another problem:).  I need to click on the child and change the color for root. But I have only the current state. that's why I try to do it via DOM

Comment: It would be impossible to understand until you share at least part of code that is explains your current problem